# Rails - How to render json with extra field in index controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using `Rails 4.0.2` with `paperclip` for image upload in my project. Also I need to send a full image path of paperclip. So I can do it with add new field and set image path manually in my `show` controller method for particular record.

**show**

```
def show
  respond_to do |format| 
    format.html
    format.json { :json => JSON::parse(@demo.to_json.merge("new_field" => @demo.image_url.url).to_json}
  end
end
```

When I view Json for any of my record, this is will showing good.

```
{
  id: "1",
  name: "demo",
  new_field: "/demo/1/original/file.jpg"
}
```

In same scenario, I need to get the full image path of paperclip image for all records when I am requesting to `index` method on `controller`

**index**

```
def index 
  @demos = Demo.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { :json => Demo.all.to_json}
  end
end
```

I tried some of codes, but I don't know how exactly to write

```
def index 
  @demos = Demo.all
  @demos.each do |demo|
     new_field = {"new_field" => @demo.image_url.url}
     # After I stucked with logic, how to uppend with 'demo'.
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { :json => Demo.all.to_json}
  end
end
```

How do I iterate my individual `Demo` model and How to merge full image path into each record.

Comment: @GraemeMcLean : Actually the problem is not from `path` or `url`. If I iterate `@demos.each do |demo|` like this, I got `@demo.image_url.url` actual result. I need to know how to append or merge with that into existing `instance object`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution for my question,

```
def index 
  @demos = Demo.all
  @demos_data = []
  @demos.each do |demo|
    new_field = {"new_field" => @demo.new_field.url}
    demo = JSON::parse(demo.to_json).merge(new_field)
    @demos_data << demo
  end

  respond_to do |format|
   format.html
   format.json { :json => @demos_data}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use two approaches, 1)use active model serializer to expose json response. 2) use jbuilder library to expose custom fields. Still you need help please let me know.

Comment: I can't get it clearly. Why I need to do that? Let me explain, `1.`how to `iterate` demo by demo and `2.` and find each `image` of demo. then `3.` how to I append that with existing one?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
def index 
  @demos = Demo.all
  @demos_data = []
  @demos.each do |demo|
    demo["new_field"] = @demo.image_url.url
    @demos_data << demo
  end

  respond_to do |format|
   format.html
   format.json { :json => @demos_data}
  end
end
```

Comment: I think `new_field` is not in `demo`, then how its possible `demo['new_field'] = ....`?

Comment: it will an extra field named as new_field in the json and can be viewed in the browser by appending .json in the url

Comment: I'm getting `undefined method 'new_field' on that same line.`.

Comment: I'm using rails 4.0.2. May be it won't work on updated version. No problem at all. Now I got solution from your idea. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try:

```
def index 
  @demos = Demo.all
  @demos.map do |demo|
    new_field = {"new_field" => @demo.image_url.url}
    demo.attributes.merge(new_field)
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { :json => @demos}
  end
end
```

`attributes` method returns a hash of all the object attributes, just need merge new key-value into the returned hash.

Comment: You should add an explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it is in your controller where you are rendering the json

```
render json: @merchants,
      include: {
        offers: {
          except: [:created_at, :updated_at],
          include: {
            categories: {
              except: [:created_at, :updated_at]
            }
          }
        },
        location: {
          methods: :country_name,
          except: [:created_at, :updated_at]
        }
      },
      except: [:created_at, :updated_at]
```

Note the `methods: :country_name`, there you can render methods from your model as json attributes. and through `include: ...` you can eager load and render related models.